# ssis expression syntax for guid

Tags: t-sql, ssis-2012

Just wondering what I am doing wrong here, I am trying to give a GUID a null value using expression. tried everything but can't seem to get the syntax working!

```
 ((ISNULL(IN_EntityId )? (DT_GUID) "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" : IN_EntityId )!= (ISNULL( EntityId) ? (DT_GUID)"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" : EntityId))
```

Comment: Looks like you pasted the expression twice? Shouldn't it be just `ISNULL(IN_EntityId )? (DT_GUID) "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" : IN_EntityId` ?

Comment: Hi, No I am using IN_ in and the other without. Its so I can distinquish between IN_ for incremental and the one without for destination. Basically one looking at source and the other one looking at destination